# In python, open.write() gives me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, time, jupyter-notebook

This Code runs and saves all the values in my output text file till `d` but does not saves my value of public_key and private_key.it is a simple code in which i am trying to replicate RSA algorithm and trying to save all the values in a text file with open.write(). Can anyone tell me where it is wrong?
It looks like this:

```
import random
import time
import os
max_PrimLength = 1000000000000

output_folder_name=f"output/{int(time.time()*100)}"
os.makedirs(f"{output_folder_name}")
details_file=open(f"{output_folder_name}/details.txt","a+")

def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return (b, 0, 1)
    else:
        g, y, x = egcd(b % a, a)
        return (g, x - (b // a) * y, y)
    
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def is_prime(num):
    if num == 2:
        return True
    if num < 2 or num % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for n in range(3, int(num**0.5)+2, 2):
        if num % n == 0:
            return False
    return True

def generateRandomPrim():
    while(1):
        ranPrime = random.randint(0,99999)
        if is_prime(ranPrime):
            return ranPrime

p = generateRandomPrim()
q = generateRandomPrim()
h = p*q
phi = (p-1) * (q-1) 
e = random.randint(1, phi)
g = gcd(e,phi)
while g != 1:
    e = random.randint(1, phi)
    g = gcd(e, phi)
        
d = egcd(e, phi)[1]
d = d % phi
if(d < 0):
    d += phi

print("First Prime Number(p): %d" % p)
details_file.write("First Prime Number(p): %d\n" % p)
print("Second Prime Number(q): %d" % q)
details_file.write("Second Prime Number(q): %d\n" % q)
print("h: %d" %h)
details_file.write("h: %d\n" %h)
print("phi(p-1)(q-1): %d" % phi)
details_file.write("phi(p-1)(q-1): %d\n" % phi)
print("e: %d" % e)
details_file.write("e: %d\n" %e)
print("d: %d" % d)
details_file.write("d: %d\n" % d)

def generate_keyPairs():
     return ((e,h),(d,h))

if _name_ == 'main':
    public_key,private_key = generate_keyPairs() 
    print("Public_Key(Traditional_RSA): ",public_key)
    details_file.write("Public_Key(Traditional_RSA): \n",public_key)
    print("Private_Key(Traditional_RSA): ",private_key)
    details_file.write("Private_Key(Traditional_RSA): \n",private_key)
    
details_file.close()
```

Trackback Error occured:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3018b2703be1> in <module>
    144     public_key,private_key = generate_keyPairs()
    145     print("Public_Key(Traditional_RSA): " ,public_key)
--> 146     details_file.write("Public_Key(Traditional_RSA): \n" ,public_key)
    147     print("Private_Key(Traditional_RSA): " ,private_key)
    148     details_file.write("Private_Key(Traditional_RSA): \n" ,private_key)

TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't mention what the error was?

Comment: @sayse it does not gives any error but does not print all the  values in the text File. I have Edited my question with the most recent trackback error please see.

Comment: Try removing the "if _name_ == 'main'" condition, and put the code out of it, it will work.

Comment: It's exactly as the error message says: you can't just specify multiple things to `.write` the same way that you would with `print`. Because this error is reached first, it hides another typo in your program: `if _name_ == 'main':` should say `if __name__ == '__main__'` instead, with two underscores on each side, for both "name" and "main". Also, keep in mind that *the point* of that block is to contain the stuff that should **not** happen if someone `import`s your file. You should follow a tutorial and make sure you understand how script files are properly organized in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving 2 arguments to the `write()` function but it only expects one - the string you want to write to the file. You should format the arguments into a single strings for your last two calls to `write()`. Something like this:

```
details_file.write("Public_Key(Traditional_RSA):" + str(public_key) + "\n")
details_file.write("Private_Key(Traditional_RSA):" + str(private_key) + "\n")
```

Comment: The outcome is not in the same line as expected. Means public_key is saved in private_key and private_key is saved in the next line.

Comment: Edited so that they are in the same line.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time, please add your expected output to your question so that others can understand the problem more effectively. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is you are giving 2 parameters to `write`, use this:

```
...
details_file.write(f"Public_Key(Traditional_RSA): \n{public_key}")
...
details_file.write(f"Private_Key(Traditional_RSA): \n{private_key}")
```

also the `__name__ == "__main__"` is used to run the code block only when file has been run directly, i.e

```
> python this_file_name.py
```

But if you import this file to another file like:

```
# other_file.py
import this_file_name
```

and run that file:

```
python other_file.py
```

Then code block under `if __name__ == "__main__":` will not run.

Comment: This is coming as output but I wanted only the Value of Public_key and Private_key.
Public_Key(Traditional_RSA):public_key
Private_Key(Traditional_RSA):private_key

Comment: are you using details_file.write or print?

Comment: I am using both...Print is used for printing the values and details_file.write is used for saving the values in text file.

Comment: So you can add only what you want. If you only want to add value of public_key and price_key, you might use:
`details_file.write(str(public_key))`, or something similar..